# Add elements to select box unless they already are present

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, jquery-selectors, unique

I'm trying to add items to a select element from another select element, but only if they are not already present:

```
$('#srcSelect option:selected').appendTo('#dstSelect')
```

The only problem with this is that I want the item in #srcSelect to be skipped if the same value already is present in #dstSelect. Or to put it another way, the values in #dstSelect should be unique.

What's the most succint way to make it so using jQuery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My solution would be to use the [.filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to filter the list of selected items to only those that don't exist in the second select:

```
$('#srcSelect option:selected').filter(function() {
    return $('#dstSelect option[value="' + $(this).attr('value') + '"]').length == 0;
}).appendTo('#dstSelect')
```

I assumed you are using a `<select multiple="multiple">` otherwise there are easier ways

Here the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/43P7M/1/

greetings Daniel